# How to update existing file on Google Drive with the Google API Node.js client?

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-drive-api, google-api-nodejs-client

Im using the [Google API Node.js client](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-nodejs-client#media-uploads) to manage files on Google Drive with a Node.js program.

I've succeeded in downloading a file using this library, now I want to upload an updated version of the file back to Google Drive.

The [documentation](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/manage-uploads#simple) explains really well how to create a **new** file on Google Drive:

```
var fileMetadata = {
  'name': 'photo.jpg'
};
var media = {
  mimeType: 'image/jpeg',
  body: fs.createReadStream('files/photo.jpg')
};
drive.files.create({
  resource: fileMetadata,
  media: media,
  fields: 'id'
}, function (err, file) {
  if (err) {
    // Handle error
    console.error(err);
  } else {
    console.log('File Id: ', file.id);
  }
});
```

However, I failed to find any information on how to overwrite an **existing** file with a new version.

Other posts on Stack Overflow [like this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40600725/google-drive-api-v3-javascript-update-file-contents), as well as the [Google docs](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/update), only explain how to use the Rest API directly for updating files.

I'm wondering if there is an easier way – since there is a nice API client library provided that lets me create new files, surely, it should also let me update existing ones?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To update the existing file, use `drive.files.update` (definition [here](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-nodejs-client/blob/00d673ba6ef401af8e27e3574d37c143dffa80e9/src/apis/drive/v3.ts#L3396)).

```js
drive.files.update({
  fileId: file.id,
  resource: fileMetadata,
  media: media
}, (err, file) => {
  if (err) {
    // Handle error
    console.error(err);
  } else {
    console.log('File Id: ', file.id);
  }
});
```

Note that you can also use the promise interface and `async`/`await` for both `drive.files.create` and `drive.files.update`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! This seems the correct solution, unfortunately, it doesn't work for me. No error is thrown, but the resulting file in Google Drive is empty (length 0 bytes). How can this be? Here's my code on GitHub: https://github.com/pahund/whats-going-on/blob/29-id-sync/src/simple-mind/uploadMindMap.js – is something missing?

Comment: @PatrickHund The API call looks correct to me (I didn't try to run your sample though, the problem might be somewhere else). I made a quick sample of the API [here](https://gist.github.com/alexander-fenster/f86ff6039e0e9dd82c268a674f1976bd) - it's self-contained (needs just a JSON API key) and straightforward (except the OAuth2 part :) ). It creates a file and then updates it. You can try starting from it.

Comment: I've figured out, the error was in the previous step, where I was writing the zip file I want to upload to the file system. I didn't await the write process being done properly. It's all good now, thanks

Comment: Thanks! I wasn't passing name field inside the resource but passing it in resource as fileMetadata object has successfully updated the file name.